# go function input, func (req *AppendEntriesRequest) Encode(w io.Writer) (int, error) {

Tags: go

```
func (req *AppendEntriesRequest) Encode(w io.Writer) (int, error) {
    pb := &protobuf.AppendEntriesRequest{
        Term:         proto.Uint64(req.Term),
        PrevLogIndex: proto.Uint64(req.PrevLogIndex),
        PrevLogTerm:  proto.Uint64(req.PrevLogTerm),
        CommitIndex:  proto.Uint64(req.CommitIndex),
        LeaderName:   proto.String(req.LeaderName),
        Entries:      req.Entries,
    }

    p, err := proto.Marshal(pb)
    if err != nil {
        return -1, err
    }

    return w.Write(p)
}
```

For this function, is "w" input? what about req? Kinda confused here.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is a Go Method

`AppendEntriesRequest` is a type and `req *AppendEntriesRequest` is a pointer to that type.
You can compare `req` in other languages as `this` or `self`

`w io.Writer` is the input of the function.

`(int, error)` are the return values.

You can invoke this method by instantiating a `AppendEntriesRequest` structure:

```
r := &AppendEntriesRequest{}
n, err := r.Encode(...)
```